# Is Conda remote repository URL working with Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

My Artifactory version is 6.6.3.

I have setup a Conda remote using the URL provided by Artifactory which is:

`https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free`

However, when i click test, Artifactory returned **404** error.

Is the remote Conda URL is wrong ?

I try to `ping repo.anaconda.com` from my Artifactory server and there is a response.

I expect the remote URL to be connected successfully when i click test button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-17552) regarding this button

You can ignore this button and use the repository as normal